# open 'mailto' from flash projector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, projector

i'm using CS3 to create a flash projector, for which i want to add a 'contact us' button, which is supposed to open the user's mail client with a mail address.
it should be simple, right? simply use - `navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:support@mysite.com"));`
well, guess what - it simply doesn't work.  if i run it in a browser, or change the 'mailto' to http address - no problem at all.  but the combination of a flash projector and mailto fail miserably. 
and no - creating AIR application is not an option, since my client wants it to be a simple EXE file.

any ideas?
cheers,
eRez

Comment: You could use third party packager like MDM's Zinc, parse the registry for the default mail application, then launch it directly.

Comment: Maybe you should check whether Flash Player's security model allows `mailto` in this context. Then also check if you set the **Local playback security** option correctly under **File > Publish Settings** of your .fla-file.

Comment: it had to do with the flash player version - i did the development in CS3, which was installed with flash player 9.  once i updated it the problem was solved.